# Get a list of installed extensions with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, ieaddon

Im trying to figure out if it is possible to get a list of all installed browser extensions using javascript

I understand it is possible on

chrom using - chrome.extension reference
firefox - using Application.extensions.all

But is it possible on IE and Safari ?

Comment: Unless the browser has provided a specific API to access this, no. Where are you running this JavaScript?

Comment: well is there a specific API for that on chrome/firefox and ie ?

Comment: What is this for though? Is this a webpage, is this an extension itself, userscript, what?

Comment: it is a webpage that suppose to list the current installed extensions

Comment: In that case unfortunately I don't think that's possible.

Comment: yeah i thought so :-) thx

Answer (score 3):

You can only do that from the Chrome Context (Firefox) or Background Script (Chrome). It is not possible to get the list of extensions from a webpage.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to get a list of all the installed extension with "Chrome tabs".[image] you only able to get extension list view extension tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

**Note: These steps are compatible with manifest V3 and V2**

1. Add **managment** permission to manifest file

   ```
   ...
   "permissions": [
      "management"
   ]
   ...
   ```
2. Call to get all installed extensions list in the background.js file

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
       const result = detectMessageType(request, sender);

       // Check if result exists
       if (result) {
           result.then(response => {
               return sendResponse(response);
           });
       }
   });

   function detectMessageType(request, sender) {

       // Check background request type
       if (request && request.type) {
           switch (request.type) {
               case 'get_all_installed_extensions': {
                   return getAllInstalledExt(request.options, sender);
               }
           }
       }
   }

   async function getAllInstalledExt() {
       const gettingAll = chrome.management.getAll();
       return await gettingAll.then(infoArray => {
           return infoArray.filter(item => item.type === "extension").map(item => item.name);
       });
   }
   ```
3. Then in your main js file of your extension app, write this to get the list of installed extensions

   ```
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'get_all_installed_extensions'}, response => {
       console.log(response); // print the list of installed extensions
   });
   ```