# Detecting if AdBlock extension is installed on the browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser, adblock

I need to detect if the Adblock extension is installed on the user's browser.

**I have seen similar question on SO, but most of them suggest to check if the DOM has been modified.**

I would rather want to check if the extension is installed (maybe with Javascript ?) on the browser rather than check the DOM. How do i do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website?rq=1

Comment: This link suggest checking DOM for changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Adblock on my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website)

Answer (score 0):

Try the global `navigator.plugins` variable. With a loop it should work. (JS)

Nice blog to the topic: http://webdevwonders.com/detecting-browser-plugins/

EDIT: For chrome you can try this if you now the APP GUID.

```
try {
    var appGUID = "nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn";
    a = new Image();
    a.src = "chrome-extension://"+appGUID+"/icon16.gif";
    if(a.width != 0) {
       //App installed!
    }
} catch(e) {
   //App not installed
}
```

Comment: I don't see AdBlock in the list of plugins for Chrome (even though I'm using it).

Comment: I too cant see Adblock in the list.

Comment: Also my browser shows 6 extensions installed whereas `navigator.plugins.length` returns `8`

Comment: Ok it shows only the "hardcore" plugins... then its not possible without dom. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website

Comment: Is it completely impossible to check external extension installations ?

Comment: yes i guess... :( check out this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830909/get-a-list-of-installed-extensions-with-javascript

Comment: This (your edit) would work, but what if they update the plugin and change image name? We **are hardcoding** the image name after all.