# List all the extensions installed in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've used chrome.management.getAll() function in order to list all the extensions installed on my google chrome browser. However, this function returns only those extensions which I have installed from the chrome web store and not those I've loaded (the one I've created).
I'm using this function with the intent to establish a communication with a second extension.

```
chrome.management.getAll(function(extInfos) {
    extInfos.forEach(function(ext) {
       console.log(ext.name);
 });
});
```

Comment: Aha, you mean "unpacked" ones. It should still return those! If not, file a bug.

Comment: Yes, it should return the unpacheck ones. Since, I'm not going to upload the extension to the web store unless it is not  completed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this! For me, `getAll()` returns unpacked extensions just fine. You should add your code where you try to enumerate extensions.

Comment: @Xan when i try to execute the script from the browser console, it does enumerate all the extensions including the unpacked ones. However, the same piece of code does return a different list when it is executed within the background of the extension!

Comment: please share your extension background page code.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaufort I edited my post, you can check the code!

Comment: @Xan oops, corrected.

Comment: I was able to get all my "development" extensions/apps with this code in `Chrome 43.0.2334.0`.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72544362/6666348

Answer (score 0):

don't you only need the `id` to do message passing between extensions ? check: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external. The `id` can be retrieved easily from the extensions list (just copy/paste) and it will stay the same when you publish your extension as well.

Comment: It will NOT stay the same as you publish, unless you take [additional steps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497781/how-to-change-chrome-packaged-app-id-or-why-do-we-need-key-field-in-the-manifest). For unpacked extensions, [it's a hash of the path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26058672/934239) to extension.

Comment: A previous question for the same author explains that there can be many extensions that listen, and keeping the list of possible IDs is impractical.