# How can I get installed chrome extensions list with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a web site made by Python Django.

And I want to check if a visitor's chrome browser's chrome extension is installed.

I found some information, it looks possible with Javascript.

https://www.python2.net/questions-993829.htm

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/management/getAll

They say you can get all installed chrome extensions by writing it like this.

chrome.management.getAll() or brower.management.getAll()

But When I tried that "chrome.management" is not defined.

Is it need to add library to use chrome.management?

I read the API documents, But I didn't know How can I to do.

Please teach me if you know about this. Thank you.

Comment: You can only get in the extension space, you cant use this in your website javascript, i hope you know that

Comment: @yk1800 I was mistaken that it was possible. I will give up on this method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of chromes docs (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/), it seems that `chrome.management` is only able to be used in chrome extensions with the `management` permission. There doesn't seem to be any real alternative for websites. (Although if you own the extension you might be able to create a hidden div with a specific id, then the website could detect that).

If chrome did allow websites to see this it would also make fingerprinting much easier.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I could do it easily, but I have to find another way.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72544362/6666348